# Letter to Numeric Phone Number Java

Tags: java, string, loops, methods, char

I have the following problem:

> Today, everyone comes up with some clever phrase so you can remember
>   their phone number. You have been given the task to decipher these
>   phrases and find out what numbers you need to dial in order to contact
>   these places.
>   **Description:** You input will be series of letters, numbers and dashes. You will need to determine the number that the input sequence
>   represents in regular three - dash- four format (see example output).
>   You will also need to determine if the resulting number is a valid
>   number (seven digits) or if there is a number in the input at all.
>   **Input:** All letters will be in uppercase. The input string may be up to 25 characters long.
>   **Output:** A single line of output is all that is needed either printing the phone number, if the number is not a valid number or if
>   there is no number at all.
>   **Translation Key** ABC = 2 DEF = 3 GHI = 4 JKL = 5 MNO = 6 PRS = 7 TUV = 8 WXY = 9   Numbers will be as themselves and ignore all Q, Z
>   and dashes.     Example Input: ITS-EASY Example Output : 487-3279
>   Example Input: ---2---3---TS-4 Example Output : Not a valid number.
>   Example Input:  QZ---I-M-A-TEST Example Output : 462-8378   Example
>   Input: ---------- Example Output : No phone number.

I'm having trouble separating the dashes and unnecessary letters from the actual phrase that translates to the phone number. This is my program so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cleverPhrase = getCleverPhrase("Input the phrase you use to remember a specific phone number (Max 25 characters allowed): ");
        checkPhrase(cleverPhrase);
    }

    public static String getCleverPhrase(String prompt) {
        String input;
        System.out.print(prompt);
        input = console.nextLine();
        return input;
    }

    public static String checkPhrase(String cleverPhrase) {
        int len = cleverPhrase.length();
        String output = "";
        do {
            for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                char current = cleverPhrase.charAt(i);

                if (Character.isLetter(current)) {
                    String newCurrent = Character.toString(current);
                    if (newCurrent.equals('Q') || newCurrent.equals('Z')) {

                    }
                }
            }
        } while ()
    }
```

As you can see, I haven't made much progress. I don't know how to get the program to pick out the unnecessary letters and dashes and return just the letters that form the number. Could someone help me?

Comment: Am I correct in guessing the assignment disallows the user of regular expressions and third-party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code..

```
public static String checkPhrase(String cleverPhrase) {
    int len = cleverPhrase.length();
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        char current = cleverPhrase.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(current)) {
            if (current == 'A' || current == 'B' || current == 'C') {
                output += "2";
            } else if (current == 'D' || current == 'E' || current == 'F') {
                output += "3";
            } else if (...) {
                ....
            }
        }
        if(output.length()==3){
            output += "-";
        }
    }

    if(output.isEmpty()){
        output = "No phone number";
    }else if(output.length()!=8){
        output = "Not a valid number";
    }
    return output;
}
```

You can extend `else-if` for all other combinations of numbers. You don't have to check for invalid characters like `-` or `Q` or `Z`. The output variable will be get edited if it goes inside a `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

To strip out the unwanted characters in your string, have a look at [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I disagree with this being a link-only answer. It is a method call that will answer the . This method is a perfectly valid answer on how to strip unwanted characters as the OP asked. More details would be nice, but still.

Answer (score 1):

This [method will be very handy in your case](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Thanks to that you can replace this

```
if (current == 'A' || current == 'B' || current == 'C')
...
} else if (current == 'D' || current == 'E' || current == 'F') {
...
```

with this

```
StringUtils.replaceChars(input, "ABCDEF", "222333")
```

You can also get rid of all non-numbers simply by `output.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )`. At the end, you can add the dash in a specific position and check if the number is valid.